# What's the multiplier amount that sets each price of an upgrade?

Tags: idle-supermarket-tycoon

So I usually install certain games on my phone which are usually tycoon games, like Cash Inc., and I got curious what could be the multiplier of each price in the game. If we want to consider what price, I'm talking about the upgrade cost, not the gained money from selling something.

For the sake of this question, what is the price multiplier (or equation) for the upgrade cost in Idle Supermarket Tycoon?

Comment: If you don't know what is Idle Supermarket Tycoon, [here](https://codigames.com/portfolio/idle-supermarket-tycoon/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact number for multiplying is 1.06. Here's how I got it:

There's a [wiki for this game](https://idle-supermarket.fandom.com/wiki/Idle_Supermarket_Wiki) for whatever reason and I decided to collect price data for the upgrades, which comes from the [third column](https://idle-supermarket.fandom.com/wiki/Building_upgrades#Produce_Department_upgrades) of the tables.

I decided to take the numbers for Produce Department, Bakery & Butcher Shop, and here are the results from LVL 2-10.

### Produce Department

```
2-3 = 1.06
3-4 = 1.0599056603773584905660377358491
4-5 = 1.0600801068090787716955941255007
5-6 = 1.0600335852225020990764063811923
6-7 = 1.059801980198019801980198019802
7-8 = 1.0601644245142002989536621823617
8-9 = 1.0599224532957349312654212195982
9-10 = 1.0601928832723644828732956434985
```

### Bakery

```
2-3 = 1.06
3-4 = 1.0660377358490566037735849056604
4-5 = 1.0619469026548672566371681415929
5-6 = 1.0666666666666666666666666666667
6-7 = 1.0625
7-8 = 1.0661764705882352941176470588235
8-9 = 1.0620689655172413793103448275862
9-10 = 1.0649350649350649350649350649351
```

### Butcher Shop

```
2-3 = 1.068
3-4 = 1.0655430711610486891385767790262
4-5 = 1.0667838312829525483304042179262
5-6 = 1.067545304777594728171334431631
6-7 = 1.0663580246913580246913580246914
7-8 = 1.0680173661360347322720694645441
8-9 = 1.0663956639566395663956639566396
9-10 = 1.0673443456162642947903430749682
```

So they're all pretty close to 1.06, so it seems reasonable that the exact number should be 1.06. Though this is not the most accurate, so there could be a formula somewhere, but I don't know how to access the in-game code.

Whatever the case, the result will always be somewhere around 1.06.